# Where are $current_user->allcaps set?

Tags: users, user-roles, capabilities, user-access

I recently found a problem with WP in which even the admin has no permission to get to anything on /wp-admin/. Oddly enough, when I compared the `$current_user->allcaps` to those on a normal site, I only saw two options, not the 40+ that usually are there. The database seems to have the administration set correctly in user_meta.

Where exactly do the caps get set? I had noticed a similar problem where the `current_user_can(...` function was actually not working when you are in 'init' hook, level 1, but a later 'init' hook did work.